# Batch snapshot PowerCLI script slow performance

Tags: powershell, scripting, vmware, esxi, powercli

I've made a powershell script which will take in a delimited batch of VM IP addresses and take snapshots of each VM.

My issue is I am calling `Get-VM` every time for every VM, which obviously is very slow. I'm wondering if anyone can see another way to perform the same action without having to call this every time?

```
Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core
$VCServer = "vc"

Connect-VIServer $VCServer
[array]$vms = (Read-Host “List of IP's (separate with comma)”).split(“,”) | %{$_.trim()}
foreach($vm in $vms)
    {
    Get-VM | where {$_.Guest.IPAddress -match $vm}| New-Snapshot -Name "Patching" -Description (Get-Date)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the `Get-VM` invoke outside the foreach, assign it to a variable and use it instead:

```
$retrievedVMs = Get-VM
foreach($vm in $vms)
{
    $retrievedVMs | where {$_.Guest.IPAddress -match $vm}| New-Snapshot -Name "Patching" -Description (Get-Date)
}
```